# When integration by parts applies?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I think integration by parts is really useful, but I don't know when integration by parts applies. Take the following proposition as an example:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, $K \subset \Omega$ a compact set, $g\in L^\infty  (\mathbb{R}^n), \phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, and $g$ is $0$ outside $K$. Define 
>   $$f(x_1,\cdots, x_n)=\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}g(y_1, x_2,\cdots, x_n)dy_1, $$
>   then
>   $$\int_{\Omega}g\phi dx=-\int_{\Omega}f\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1} dx.$$

It seems this should be proved with integration by parts, but since the function $f$ is not differentiable (only continuous w.r.t $x_1$), I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What function is not differentiable? $\phi$ certainly is.

Comment: We know more than that $f$ is just continuous in $x_1$. We know it is Lipschitz-continuous in $x_1$ (and bounded), hence the product $f\cdot \phi$ is also Lipschitz-continuous with respect to $x_1$, hence absolutely continuous, and the fundamental theorem of calculus applies.

Comment: Yes, I got the same idea just now! Thank!